# How to handle JSON documents that have float values with no leading zeroes before decimal points?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to load some json data in python pandas using the `json_normalize()` like so:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

data_json = json_normalize(json.loads(data))
```

However, I'm getting a `JSONDecodeError`. I've figured out it is because of a value that has floats on the form `.55` instead of `0.55`.

How can I handle this case?

update: added `import son` to the code snippet which I had forgotten earlier.

Comment: is there an `import json` missing?

Comment: no it's there. guess I should have shown that as well. correcting that. i'm pretty sure the error occurs because of floats without a leading 0. though.

Comment: What you have is not JSON. Fix the producer of broken output, not the consumer. (Also, include a relevant sample of your input, please.)

Comment: @Tomalak is correct about JSON and so are you about .55 being the trouble.  I was surprised to just now discover the .55 is not a legal JSON number according to json.org.